# Get student details and other relationships in one query and store in one object in mySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
1. Students
- StudentID
- StudentName
- etc...

2. Students_Classes
- StudentID
- ClassID

3. Classes
- ClassID
- ClassName
- etc...
```

Currently, I have two queries to store a Student details and his classes by this way

**First**, I run this query and return result to PHP object I call **$Student**:

```
select StudentID, StudentName, etc..., group_concat(DISTINCT stu_to_cla.ClassID) as currentStudentClassesID from Students LEFT JOIN (Students_Classes as stu_cla, Student.StudentID = stu_cla.StudentID) where StudentID = 1
```

**Second**, I use **$ClassesID =  explode(',' , $Student['currentStudentClassesID']** to an array and pass it to second query:

```
select(ClassID, ClassName, etc... from (Classes) where ClassesID IN ($ClassesID)
```

Now I have two objects, one stores student information and another with his classes information.

My question is can I improve it with only one query that return both his information and his classes and how can I use it properly in PHP ?

**UPDATE**

Now I have another situation when I have several relationship like: Students - Classes, Student - Dorm, Student - States...

So can I get all of one student information about everything and store it in **ONLY** one object in PHP ? How should I build the  the most effective and light-weight mySQL query? **Use one big query to get everything at once** or **build the student object first** and then **build other relationship objects after that** ?

Comment: Use concept of JOIN for single query : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Your first query would return a syntax error

Comment: Incidentally, if that DISTINCT is necessary then you likely have severe problems with your data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.StudentID
     , s.StudentName
     , c.ClassID
     , c.classname
  from Students s 
  JOIN `Students-Classes`  sc
    ON sc.StudentID = s.StudentID
  JOIN classes c
    ON c.classid = sc.classid
 where s.StudentID = 1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This method will return every ClassID and ClassName with duplicate Student information in every records. If I need student information, I only need to call first record in query array. If I need classes information, I will put the result array in the loop.

Comment: Yes. The method I describe above is the correct approach.

Comment: ...and this principle is extendable regardless of the size and complexity of the query

Comment: but if I have two or more tables relate with Student table, could that possible using one query to get them all ? For example: Students-Classes and Students-Dorm.